# Select Max correct answers for a user in 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 4 tables

```
Users
ID
Name

Questions
ID
Question


User_Answers
ID
User_ID
Answer
Question_ID


Correct_Answers
ID
Question_ID
Answer_ID
```

so for example, I have these data

```
Users
ID = 3
Name = Jack
ID = 4
Name = Mike
--------------------
Questions

ID = 3
Question = text for a question
ID = 4
Question = text for a question
-----------------

User_Answers
ID = 1
User_ID = 3
Answer = 0
Question_ID = 3

ID = 2
User_ID = 3
Answer = 1
Question_ID = 3

ID = 3
User_ID = 3
Answer = 1
Question_ID = 3

ID = 4
User_ID = 3
Answer = -1
Question_ID = 3

ID = 5
User_ID = 3
Answer = 0
Question_ID = 3

ID = 6
User_ID = 3
Answer = 1
Question_ID = 3

-------------------------

Correct_Answers
ID = 1
Question_ID  = 3
Answer = 0

ID = 2
Question_ID  = 4
Answer = -1

ID = 3
Question_ID  = 5
Answer = 0
```

I need sql query to get me the most user with the correct answers

```
SELECT * 
FROM users,correct_answers,questions,user_answers 
WHERE correct_answers.answer = user_answers.answer 
  AND user_answers.question_id = correct_answers.question_id
```

This wont work as I want, I need I think a sub query to count the correct answer and get the max :(

This is the sqlfiddle link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b53a7/3

how I can do it ?

Thanks

Comment: please add some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com along with the desired output to the questions from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.user_id, count(b.ID) as maxAnswers 
from user_answers a 
inner join correct_answers b on a.answer=b.answer 
and a.question_id = b. question_id 
group by a.user_id 
order by maxAnswers desc 
limit 1;
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, a code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would explain what the code is doing and how to use it.  It would also link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As for your table structure query for the user with the most correct answers :

```
Select sq.User_ID, sq.Name, sum(Correctness) as Most_Correct
  from (select ua.User_ID, u.Name, if(ua.Answer = ca.Answer, 1, 0) as 
    Correctness from  Users_Answers ua join Questions q 
      on ua.Question_ID = q.ID join correct_answers ca
       on ua.Question_ID= ca.Question_ID join Users u on ua.User_ID = u.ID) as sq
  group by User_ID Desc Order by Most_Correct desc limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aa82/1

You can also create the schema like as follows :

Users

```
ID    |      Name
```

Questions

```
ID    |      Question     |    Answer
```

User_Answers

```
ID    |      User_ID      |    Answer      |    Question_ID
```

Query for the user with the most correct answers :

```
Select sq.User_ID, sq.Name, sum(Correctness) as Most_Correct
   from (select ua.User_ID, u.Name, if(ua.Answer = q.Answer, 1, 0) as Correctness
      from  User_Answers ua join Questions q 
          on ua.Question_ID = q.ID join User u on ua.User_ID = u.ID) as sq
              group by User_ID Desc Order by Most_Correct desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Yeah I know, I didnt create the schema, they already got it but I need to get the user with the most correct answers